# N images in a strip

Tags: graphics

I needed something (a package, a macro, whatever) that would take n images of arbitrary size and calculate their height so that all the images side by side filled a column exactly. As far as I know, there is no such package. The nearest thing I found was this: [How to define a macro that uses image width and height to define a variable for later use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122299/how-to-define-a-macro-that-uses-image-width-and-height-to-define-a-variable-for). I modified the solution offered there to accept any number of images. I put it here in the hope that someone may find it useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\myheight%
\newlength\mywidth%
\newlength\effwidth%
\newlength\finalheight%
\newlength\gapspace%

\newcommand{\manyimages}[2]{

\setlength{\gapspace}{#2}%
\pgfmathsetlength{\effwidth}{0.99\textwidth - \gapspace}%

\def\sumratio{0}

\foreach \im [remember=\sumratio] in {#1} {%

    \def\myimage{\includegraphics{\im}}%
    \setlength{\myheight}{\heightof{\myimage}}%
    \setlength{\mywidth}{\widthof{\myimage}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myratio}{\mywidth / \myheight}%

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\sumratio}{\sumratio+\myratio}
}%

\pgfmathsetlength{\finalheight}{\effwidth / \sumratio}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\manyimages{image1, image2, image3, image4}{0.06\textwidth}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{image1}}
\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{image2}}
\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{image3}}
\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{image4}}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. `\manyimages` has two arguments. The first argument is a comma-separated list of images. The second argument is the gap space between them (the total gap, to be split in n-1 gaps).
2. The code needs real images with arbitrary sizes, otherwise the problem is trivial. Therefore I don't put the graphics in demo mode.
3. I'm new to LaTeX and StackExchange, I appreciate input about best practices, etc.

Comment: Are these related to what you are trying to do?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125675/automatic-scaling-of-tikz-images-in-floatrow/125722#125722 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121973/adjust-link-target-for-rotated-two-part-figure/126393#126393

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely I misunderstood the question due to lack of sleep... but what you want is not simply this?:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]\bigskip

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image-golden}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image-golden-upright}}

\bigskip\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

**Note**: 
I forget to put `%` after each image, so that a space is added between the images. When the fixed `height` is enough big, the result is roughly the same, but with very low values (try for instance `1 mm` in this example) the space is upscaled giving the appearance of `\hfill` commands between the images. Funnily, `\hfill` here just prevented this spacing (please, do not consider this a recommendation of alternative usage).

Comment: Thank you! You didn't misunderstand. It is indeed that. A little background: I'm new to TeX and LaTeX. I needed this feature for my first project, a few months ago. I found my question had been asked on a different forum, and the answers boiled down to "trial and error". That didn't seem too clever because, as @egreg pointed out, mathematically it is straightforward. At the time, I settled for manual calculations. Now I am teaching myself LaTeX. I'm happy to learn that this problem is very simple, and that several different approaches all work. I hope other beginners will find it.

Comment: You're welcome. In my experience, this is largely the best Q&A site about TeX\LaTeX.

Answer (score 9):

Some linear algebra shows that the final height is given by the formula

[image]

where *w* is the desired global width, *b*<sub>*i*</sub> and *h*<sub>*i*</sub> are the width and height of the *i*-th image (*i* = 1,2,…,n); *h$ is the final height.

An implementation using `expl3` is almost straightforward. I guess that it's easy also with `pgfmath`. The macro `\manyimages` has as first argument the desired width (*w* in the preceding notation) which can be whatever one wants. In the following example I chose `0.8\textwidth` to give the images some room.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\manyimages}{ m m }
 {
  % #1 is the required width
  % #2 is a comma separated list of image names
  \manyimages_main:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\fp_new:N \l_manyimages_temp_fp
\box_new:N \l_manyimages_temp_box
\dim_new:N \l_manyimages_finalheight_dim

\cs_set_eq:NN \finalheight \l_manyimages_finalheight_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manyimages_main:nn #1 #2
 {
  % clear the storage bin
  \fp_zero:N \l_manyimages_temp_fp
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    % set a temporary box for measuring the current image
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_manyimages_temp_box { \includegraphics{##1} }
    % compute the ratio width/height and add it to the storage bin
    \fp_add:Nn \l_manyimages_temp_fp 
     {
      \dim_to_fp:n { \box_wd:N \l_manyimages_temp_box }
      /
      \dim_to_fp:n { \box_ht:N \l_manyimages_temp_box } 
     }
   }
  % now set \finalheight to the ratio w/(computed sum)
  \dim_set:Nn \l_manyimages_finalheight_dim
   {
    \fp_to_dim:n { \dim_to_fp:n { #1 } / \l_manyimages_temp_fp }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\manyimages{0.8\textwidth}{
  example-image,
  example-image-10x16,
  example-image-golden,
  example-image-golden-upright
}

\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{example-image-10x16}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{example-image-golden}\hfill
\includegraphics[height=\finalheight]{example-image-golden-upright}

\bigskip

For control

\bigskip

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \includegraphics{example-image-10x16}
  \includegraphics{example-image-golden}
  \includegraphics{example-image-golden-upright}%
}


\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I have used some images in the `mwe` suite. The second row is just for control and shows the images at their (uniformly scaled) original proportions.

[image]

Here is a full featured solution for `subfig`. For typesetting a row of images we use the `manysubfloats` environment, which contains one or more `\subimage` commands. The mandatory argument to `manysubfloats` is a dimension; use whatever you want, but recall that using `\textwidth` would push all the images together.

You can have more than one `manysubfloats` environments, each one will print a row of subfloats.

Each `\subimage` command has two arguments: the first is an optional list of key-value pairs, the second is the file name. In the key-value pairs one can specify

- `file=` for the file name;
- `path=` for a non standard path;
- `caption=` for setting the subcaption;
- `listcaption=` for a possibly different subcaption in the list of figures;
- `label=` for a label referring to the subfloat.

Why a key `file`? If the file name has special characters or is too long, a symbolic name for the mandatory argument is to be preferred. The mandatory argument is used for internal purposes only. The `file=` key is probably not necessary, as most of the time the file name can be safely used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{manysubfloats}{ m }
 { \clist_clear:N \l_manyimages_row_clist }
 { \manyimages_display:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\subimage}{ O{} m }
 {% #1 is a key-value list, #2 is a symbolic name or the file name
  \manyimages_subimage:nn { #2 } { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { manyimages }
 {
  file .tl_set:N = \l_manyimages_file_tl,
  path .tl_set:N = \l_manyimages_path_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_manyimages_caption_tl,
  listcaption .tl_set:N = \l_manyimages_listcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N = \l_manyimages_label_tl
 }


\fp_new:N \l_manyimages_temp_fp
\box_new:N \l_manyimages_temp_box
\dim_new:N \l_manyimages_finalheight_dim
\clist_new:N \l_manyimages_row_clist
\tl_new:N \l_manyimages_output_tl
\tl_new:N \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_manyimages_tmpb_tl

% a constant property list
\prop_new:N \c_manyimages_proto_prop
\prop_gput:Nnn \c_manyimages_proto_prop { file } { }
\prop_gput:Nnn \c_manyimages_proto_prop { path } { }
\prop_gput:Nnn \c_manyimages_proto_prop { caption } { }
\prop_gput:Nnn \c_manyimages_proto_prop { listcaption } { }
\prop_gput:Nnn \c_manyimages_proto_prop { label } { }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manyimages_main:n #1
 {
  % clear the storage bin
  \fp_zero:N \l_manyimages_temp_fp
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_manyimages_row_clist
   {
    % set a temporary box for measuring the current image
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { path } \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { file } \l_manyimages_tmpb_tl
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_manyimages_temp_box
     {
      \includegraphics
       {
        \tl_if_empty:NF \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl { \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl / }
        \l_manyimages_tmpb_tl
       }
     }
    % compute the ratio width/height and add it to the storage bin
    \fp_add:Nn \l_manyimages_temp_fp 
     {
      \dim_to_fp:n { \box_wd:N \l_manyimages_temp_box }
      /
      \dim_to_fp:n { \box_ht:N \l_manyimages_temp_box } 
     }
   }
  % now set \finalheight to the ratio w/(computed sum)
  \dim_set:Nn \l_manyimages_finalheight_dim
   {
    \fp_to_dim:n { \dim_to_fp:n { #1 } / \l_manyimages_temp_fp }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manyimages_subimage:nn #1 #2
 {% add the item to the clist
  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_manyimages_row_clist { #1 }
  % clear the property list for #1 (symbolic name or file name)
  \prop_clear_new:c { l_manyimages_\tl_to_str:n { #1 }_prop }
  % fill in the property list with empty values
  \prop_set_eq:cN { l_manyimages_\tl_to_str:n { #1 }_prop } \c_manyimages_proto_prop
  \keys_set:nn { manyimages }
   {% empty the variables and evaluate the given ones
    file = {},
    path = {},
    caption = {},
    listcaption = {},
    label = {},
    #2
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_manyimages_file_tl
   {
    \__manyimages_prop_put:nnn { #1 } { file } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \__manyimages_prop_put:nnV { #1 } { file } \l_manyimages_file_tl
   }
  \__manyimages_prop_put:nnV { #1 } { path } \l_manyimages_path_tl
  \__manyimages_prop_put:nnV { #1 } { caption } \l_manyimages_caption_tl
  \__manyimages_prop_put:nnV { #1 } { listcaption } \l_manyimages_listcaption_tl
  \__manyimages_prop_put:nnV { #1 } { label } \l_manyimages_label_tl
 }

%%% syntactic sugar
% a personal version of \prop_put:cnn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__manyimages_prop_put:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prop_put:cnn { l_manyimages_\tl_to_str:n { #1 }_prop } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__manyimages_prop_put:nnn { nnV }

% a personal version of \prop_get:cnN
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prop_get:cnN { l_manyimages_\tl_to_str:n { #1 }_prop } { #2 } #3
 }

%%% use \subfloat
\cs_new_protected:Npn \manyimages_display:n #1
 {% compute the final height
  \manyimages_main:n { #1 }
  % output the subfloats
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_manyimages_row_clist
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_manyimages_output_tl { \subfloat }
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { listcaption } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_manyimages_output_tl { [ }
      \tl_put_right:NV \l_manyimages_output_tl \l_tmpa_tl
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_manyimages_output_tl { ] }
     }
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { caption } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_manyimages_output_tl { [ }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl
     {
      \tl_put_right:NV \l_manyimages_output_tl \l_tmpa_tl
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_manyimages_output_tl { ] }
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { label } \l_tmpa_tl
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { path } \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl
    \__manyimages_prop_get:nnN { ##1 } { file } \l_manyimages_tmpb_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_manyimages_output_tl
     {
      {
       \exp_not:N \includegraphics
         [height=\l_manyimages_finalheight_dim]
         {
          \tl_if_empty:NF \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl { \l_manyimages_tmpa_tl / }
          \l_manyimages_tmpb_tl
         }
       \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:N \label { \l_tmpa_tl } }
      }
     }
    \tl_use:N \l_manyimages_output_tl\hfill
   }
  \unskip
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{manysubfloats}{.9\textwidth}
\subimage{example-image}

\subimage[
  file=example-image-10x16
]{10x16}

\subimage[
  caption=Yikes,
  listcaption=Ouch,
  path=images
]{example-image-golden}

\subimage[
  label=subfig:upright
]{example-image-golden-upright}
\end{manysubfloats}
\caption{Cumulative caption}
\end{figure}

A reference: \subref{subfig:upright}

\end{document}
```

[image]